# How to show hide multiple pages in angularjs in single section

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 pages 1.html, 2.html and 3.html and having 3 different buttons button1, button2 and button3. On button1 click i want to show 1.html and on button2 2.html and so on. How can we achieve this in angularJs?

Comment: you could do this with the angular router `ng-route`, a 3rd party state provider like `ui-router`, manually using `ng-include`, or a few other ways.  This is way too broad to just throw you all the possible ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-include to achieve this, move your html to script tags and change ng-include values on button click
Here is the example [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

Comment: can you please help me with example?

Comment: There is an example in the bottom of the link check that.

Comment: I have moved my html code to script  'vm.templates =
    [{ name: 'template1.html', url: 'template1.html'},
     { name: 'template2.html', url: 'template2.html'}];' and calling name on button click event. ' <button id="editProfile" ng-click="vm.template.template2">' but still its not working. and '<div class="col-md-8" ng-include="vm.template.url">'

Comment: ng-click="changeTemplate(''template2.html') 
$scope.changeTemplate=function(name){
$scope.template.url = name
}

Answer (score -1):

Why not use `ui-router` ?
[Follow this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router)